# Reset all the changes I have made to the html of my wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress

I screwed up something editing the html of my wordpress theme (Old Paper). I want to find a way to restore the html before I started messing with it. Is that possible?

Comment: Not if you didn't back up your work (*Always* keep your work backed up). You'll have to download & reinstall the theme. And never make changes directly to themes files in future - create child themes to make you own changes.

Comment: Use Git for future to avoid that kind of problem.

Comment: get the original theme, replace the files that you messed up with the original. That's it.